# Segmentation Fault 11 in C with Struct?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, structure, fault

I am currently having a segmentation fault 11 in this code here. I am trying to read an input file and store it into my structure. Whenever I run, it only prints out the first item of the text file, then it gives me a Segmentation Fault 11 error. What could be causing this?

Here is my code:

```
    typedef struct{
    int serialNum;
    char giftName[50];
    int price;
    char store[50];
} product;

void read_File(const char *filename)
{
    filename = "items.txt";
    product p[4] = {0};
    int i = 0;
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (file){
        char line[100];
        while(fgets(line, sizeof line, file) && i < 6){
            fputs(line, stdout);
            if (sscanf(line, "%d %s %d %s", 
                p[i].serialNum,
                p[i].giftName,
                p[i].price,
                p[i].store) == 5)
                {
                    printf("Storing information in structure complete.");
                }
        }
    
    fclose(file);
}
else{
    perror(filename);
}
}
```

Comment: Why is your limit `i < 6` (i.e. `i <= 5`) when `p` has only `4` members?

Comment: Several issues here. Your `while` loop never increments `i` so its value is always 0. You've allocated space for 4 products, but your `i < 6` suggests you'll allow up to 6. You are checking `sscanf` for result of 5, but you are only scanning for 4 items.

Comment: And actually reading of unlimited lines is allowed because `i` is not changed.

Comment: Just one tip, don't use `sscanf()` as a condition. It makes debugging harder and the `if` much less readable

Comment: You're doing 4 assignments with `sscanf`. Why are you comparing the result with 5?

Answer (score 1):

To read integers via `sscanf()` (or other `scanf()` family), you have to pass *pointers* so that `sscanf()` can write the integers read using the pointers.

On the other hand, to read *strings* via `sscanf()`, you need not and shouldn't add `&` because the arrays will be automatically converted to the pointers to the first elements.

Also it is weird to check `== 5` while there are only 4 things to read.

```
            if (sscanf(line, "%d %s %d %s", 
                &p[i].serialNum, /* add & to pass pointer */
                p[i].giftName,
                &p[i].price, /* add & to pass pointer */
                p[i].store) == 4) /* correct number */
```